# How to check if current time falls in a specific schedule using PHP (and if not calculate the next time)?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, php-carbon

I'm trying to write a task scheduler kind of program (more or less an analogy) that needs to print if the current time is inside a specific schedule. If not, then it needs to find the *next run* time (i.e. closest time in future that falls under the schedule) and print that instead.

The schedule format is JSON and looks something like this:

```
[
 {"days": ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"], "start_time":"09:00", "end_time":"18:00"},
 {"days": ["Sat"],"start_time":"06:00","end_time":"12:00"}
]
```

What the above means is that the allowed schedule is between 9am to 6pm on weekdays, 6am to 12pm on Saturday and nothing happens on Sunday (this is just an example, there can be many items and possible overlaps also)

So let's say today is `Thu 19:00`, then it will print "NO" followed by `Fri 09:00` the closest time.

Another example, let's say it is `Sat 13:00` then it will again print "NO" followed by `Mon 09:00` since Sunday is not in the schedule.

On the other hand if now is `Tue 11:00` then it will just print "YES" (because it falls in the above schedule).

I've tried to implement it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d72bad6cf2471383adb616a6edce1c24879af36) and it works, but I think my implementation is rather slow since I loop over each and every day to check when it passes and I'm sure there must exists a much faster way to compute the future time directly.

Thanks for your help!

P.S. The timezone is always UTC (if it matters). I've already installed `Carbon` and open to using any libraries if that makes the job easier.

Comment: You could skip your inner loop if the day of week is not in the list of days. While your open/close format does prevent duplicate data, it makes it harder to find the next date. If not open, you have to move $current to the next day, loop over the outer dimension looking to see if that day is in the list of days until you find it. If you changed your data to be `[dow => [open, close], dow2=>...]` and it was sorted by key, it would be as simple as moving to the next element in the array (or first element if overflow past last).